# OLS is BLUE (or BUE) to minimize MSE. Is quantile regression is BLUE to minimize MAE?

Tags: least-squares, quantile-regression, gauss-markov-theorem

The Gauss-Markov theorem considers "best" as "lowest mean square error (MSE)" and a recent version of the theorem shows OLS is not only BLUE but also BUE: [https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/papers/gauss.pdf](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ebhansen/papers/gauss.pdf)

When the "best" becomes "lowest mean absolute error (MAE)", is it the case that the best estimator is no longer OLS and perhaps quantile (median) regression?

Comment: The empirical median is a lower-variance (and unbiased) estimator of the mean of a Laplace distribution than the empirical mean (which is the OLS estimator). Estimating the mean corresponds to regression on just an intercept term, so this is a regression. Consequently, the claim about BUE instead of just BLUE is false.